# how can I refactor methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I have written the following 3 methods:

Method Nr. 1:

```
var carYear = cars.filter(function(item) {
  if (item.year > 1999) {
    return item;
  };
})
```

Method Nr. 2

```
var carVolvo = cars.filter(function(item) {
  if (item.make == 'Volvo') {
    return item;
  };
});
```

Method Nr. 3

```
var carPrice = cars.filter(item => item.price < 5000);
```

How can I refactor the methods, that takes the filter text as an argument?

And how can I refactor all of this into one method, that takes the filter text, and type, as arguments?

Comment: Refactoring requests for working code are off-topic here. [Codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the appropriate place for such questions

Comment: @hindmost, right, but that requires working code, which is not given (for that requirement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function like this that accepts parameters and replace the AND(&&) with OR(||) depending on your preference if it should match all param or at least one.

```
function filterCars(year, make, price) {
    return cars.filter(c => c.year > year && c.make === make && c.price < price);
}
```

Comment: all of your answers are good. But I think AlMusal 's answer is what im looking for. Thanks to all of you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could move the filters into an array and check either if only one filter matches the actual car (or condition) or all filters matches the car (and condition).

```
filters = [
    item => item.year > 1999,
    item => item.make == 'Volvo',
    item => item.price < 5000
];

onlyOneFilter = cars.filter(car => filters.some(fn => fn(car)));
allFilters = cars.filter(car => filters.every(fn => fn(car)));
```

Comment: Nina can you explain your methods for me. I dont understand them?

Comment: the `filters` array contains all wanted callbacks which return a boolean value for filtering. [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) returns `true` if one callback returns true of the array of condition functions. [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) need that all functions return true of the callback array.

Comment: i thinkk you're answer is very advanced. Im new to JS, so it's hard for me to understand it right now. But many thanks, anyway!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Nina Scholz's approach. Regardless as a 100% compliant answer to OP question

> How can I refactor the methods, that takes the filter text as an argument?

```
function filterSwitcher(filterText) {
    switch(filterText) {
        case "year":
            return item => item.year > 1999
        case "make":
            return item => item.make == 'Volvo'
        case "price":
            return item => item.price < 5000
    }
}

cars.filter(filterSwitcher("price"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor like this

```js
var arrs = [{price:1500},{price:1900},{price:2000}]
var obj = {a:[],b:[],c:[]}
arrs.filter(function(item){
  if(item.price<1600){
     obj.a.push(item)
     return
   }else if(item.price<2000) {
      obj.b.push(item)
       return   
 }else{
      obj.c.push(item)
      return
   }
})
```

Comment: How is your code different from my. I think it's pretty similar. so im not sure its the answers to my request.